# R plotly how to plot 3D lines by multiple groups?

Tags: r, plotly

I am new to `plotly()` trying to plot 3D lines, and found it different from ggplot(). It is not grouping like in ggplot() which allows `interaction()` for grouping, and connecting all the points like geom_line rather than geom_path. Currently, I have below code that is not grouping:

```
dt%>%
  plot_ly(x = ~x.center, y = ~y.center, z = ~z.center, type = 'scatter3d', 
  color = ~interaction(spreadsheet_row,participant.id), ##key issue!
  mode = 'lines', opacity = 1, line = list(width = 3,  reverscale = FALSE))
```

The sample data for testing can be like

```
dt <- data.table(x.center=rnorm(100), y.center=rnorm(100), z.center=rnorm(100), spreadsheet_row=sample(1:20, 100, replace=T), participant=paste0('P-', sample(1:10, 100, replace=T)))
```

I want points to be connected like `geom_path` and grouped by 'participant' and 'spreadsheet_row'. Please help.

Comment: I chose to plot this data with `ggplot` so that I could see the difference between what `path` and `line` gave me. The graphs are nearly identical. Then I looked at the data you provided. That's 200 groups. Can you provide a bit more information regarding what it is you're looking for?

Comment: @Kat How could ggplot show identical 3D plots as plotly?

Comment: The 2 `ggplot` were nearly identical. Additionally, I only used x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your groups in the `split` argument like below, and you can remove the `line` argument.

`split= ~ interaction(spreadsheet_row, participant.id)`

Comment: Brilliant! I know there should be a straightforward config. Thanks.